# How to ignore hour minute and second while inserting date in `MongoDB`

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I am storing `Date(17-01-2019)` in data base, But when I see in data base it looks like `2019-01-17 05:30:00.000`.

```
public <T> T findOne(Query query, Class<T> entityClass)
```

This MongoTemplate method that I am implementing and writing the query

```
findOne(Criteria
    .where(RoomStatusEntity.FIELDS.ROOM_ID)
    .is(roomId)
    .and(RoomStatusEntity.FIELDS.START_DATE).is(startDate)
    .and(RoomStatusEntity.FIELDS.END_DATE).is(endDate)
)
```

The main problem is when I try to fetch data by using the `date(17-01-2019)` it's not returning the data. This problem is coming if I run the code on server, if I run in local system that time it is storing in `2019-01-17 00:00:00.000`

Comment: There are 2 ways to solve this, one is to store the date in the format "2019-01-17 00:00:00.000", which I won't recommend. The other is to improve your find call, can you write down the query you're using to retrieve by date ?

Comment: `public <T> T findOne(Query query, Class<T> entityClass)`  This `MongoTemplate` method that I am implementing and writing the query `findOne(
    Criteria.where(RoomStatusEntity.FIELDS.ROOM_ID).is(roomId).and(RoomStatusEntity.FIELDS.START_DATE)
      .is(startDate).and(RoomStatusEntity.FIELDS.END_DATE).is(endDate))`